YOLOv10: how to interpret training progress info?
I'm training YOLOv10 with this code:
model.train(
  .........
  epochs=250,
  batch=16,
  verbose=True,
  save=True,
  save_period=1,
  time=4,
  .........
)

I'm trying various VM/GPU options to calculate the most cost-effective options for training, so I run it many times, at the same time I change batch to fill GPU RAM close to 90%.
During the training, besides other output, I get info like on the screenshot.

The questions are below. I allowed myself to ask a few questions in one topic because I expect two of them to be more or less as simple as yes/no/single_word and another to be just a link.

Why the planned number of epochs (1) was changed (2)? I believe it can be because the time allocated for training was limited so the training process calculates how many epochs it can run during this time, but I'm unsure.
I believe (3) is the number of batches per epoch, this number changes depending on the batch size and GPU RAM usage. Is it correct?
How can I estimate how long the training process will take (assuming there's no time limit configured) on a particular GPU/batch setup? I tried to sum (4) and (5) and multiply by the changed number of epochs (2) but in all experiments, I always got time close to the configured limit.
Is there documentation explaining all the other data on the screenshot as well as the other training output? Some values are self-explanatory, some are not so I prefer to avoid guessing. I checked https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/train/ but found no explanation.

